# How to exit the package that I'm just using in common lisp?

Tags: package, common-lisp

I define a package

```
 [10]> (defpackage :abc)
 #<PACKAGE ABC>
 [11]>
```

I use that package

```
 [15]> (in-package :abc)
 #<PACKAGE ABC>
 ABC[16]>
```

How to exit ABC[16] to [17] ?

Thank you~

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strictly speaking you don't use the package with `in-package` but you
set the current package. To use a package you've to use `use-package`.

Back to your problem, you've defined a new package (without using `:cl`
so you'll have to use `(cl:+ 1 2)` to do an addition) and set it as
the current package. `COMMON-LISP-USER` a.k.a. `CL-USER` is the
current package when you start your lisp system, thus to have it back
you just have to do `(cl:in-package :cl-user)`.

[Here](http://www.flownet.com/gat/packages.pdf) is a nice tutorial on packages in Common Lisp. [This chapter](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/programming-in-the-large-packages-and-symbols.html)
in PCL is also very good. But the reference is still the [CLHS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/c_packag.htm)

Comment: Or, indeed, `(cl:in-package :cl-user)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should get back to the `:cl-user` package by `(in-package :cl-user)`. 
Common Lisp packages are generally a bit confusing for the new comers. I also recommend you to read [Erann Gat's tutorial](http://www.flownet.com/gat/packages.pdf) on packages.
As a convention, in the case of a serious (i.e big) program, people tend to make package definitions in a separate file which includes `(defpackage :foo ... )`and the real code goes into another one which generally begins with `(in-package :foo)`. Then by the help of a system definition facility like [ASDF](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/), the file which consists of
package definitions are evaled and loaded before the actual file.
According to my humble view and experience, the easiest way to solve the package mystery is to read actual code developed by experienced lispers after a quick tutorial session.